# Footer Not Fixing in Windows Mobile App

Tags: windows

My Footer is not fixing in my Windows mobile app.

code : 
.newFooter {bottom:0; position:absolute !important; width:100%;}

Note: This codes works for Android,BB,Ios.

Can any one help me with some Good Solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
/* Start - Used to display the footer at the bottom of the page */
html,
body {
margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;
}

#container {
min-height:100%;position:relative;
}

#header {
}

#content {
padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}

#footer {
width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;
}
/* End - Used to display the footer at the bottom of the page */
```

Comment: This Code Works For All- Mobile and Web.